# Android Launcher get Camera icon and label

Tags: android, camera, icons, launcher

I'm trying to replicate the application grid that Android have by default, loading all the "launchable" appliactions.

I do it this way.

```
//generate the intent to get the application list 
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
applicationList = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

//sort the list 
Collections.sort(applicationList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));

//user in calculating percentage. 
if (applicationList.size() > 0 ){
    for (ResolveInfo info : applicationList) {
```

once I've the list handle it to show the name + icon of the application in a grid view, but when it comes to the camera, I keep getting the Gallery label and icon.

for getting the label I use:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
(String) manager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)
```

for getting the icon

```
info.loadIcon(getContext().getPackageManager());
```

where info is a ApplicationInfo object.

I wonder what could be happening.

so far I've just notice that application but it maybe another.

anyone know how can I get the Camera application from the camera ResolveInfo

while debuging I toke an screen shot this is the information I got for that ResolveInfo

[image: Camera Resolve Info (information)]

Thanks in advice. 
Cesar Glez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder what could be happening.

You are getting the icon and the label for the application. The "Camera" and the "Gallery" come from a single app with two launchable activities.

You need to get the icon and the label for the *activity*, not the *application*. Call `loadLabel()` and `loadIcon()` on the `ResolveInfo` to get the icon and label for the activity that the `ResolveInfo` points to.

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) demonstrates building such a launcher, and it correctly gets the camera activity icon for its entry.

Comment: Worked as a charm thanks a lot. just if one more question could you point me to some documentation on that, this because I still not clear on what information can I get from each application.

Comment: @cesaregb: Get documentation on... what? `PackageManager`, `ApplicationInfo`, `ResolveInfo`, and kin are all in the JavaDocs.